# Parallel Blob processing with Azure WebJobs

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-webjobs

I have multiple instances of a WebSite, all running the same WebJob, connected to the same AzureWebJobsStorage and configured to trigger on incoming blobs.

Unfortunetely, the result is different from what I intended - when a blob is saved to the storage, only one of the WebJobs instances picks it up. I would rather have all of them process this blob. My guess is that it works like this beacuse of how the blob receipt name is constructed - it contains the WebJob funcion name which is the same for all my WebJobs.

Is there any way to have the blob processed by all WebJob instances in this situation?

Comment: Can you add your method declaration with `BlobTriggerAttribute` ?

Answer (score 2):

I just found an answer to this question by myself. It turns out that one can configure the **HostId** which gets included in the blob's receipt name. For me, the following piece of code does the job:

```
var applicationName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBSITE_SITE_NAME");

var host = new JobHost(new JobHostConfiguration
                                       {
                                           HostId = applicationName ?? "localhost"
                                       });
```